# How to merge two rows and get result?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Table Data:

sales_products table data:

| product_id | quantity | sales price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 300 |
| 1 | 5 | 300 |
| 2 | 3 | 400 |
| 2 | 2 | 400 |
| 3 | 3 | 100 |

products table

| id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | product_x |
| 2 | product_y |
| 3 | product_z |

Expected Query Output

| product_name | Quantity | Total_Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product_x | 9 | 2700 |
| product_y | 5 | 2000 |
| product_z | 3 | 300 |

I was trying with following Query and didn't get expected output

```
$invoiceDetails = DB::table('products')
    ->join('sales_products', 'sales_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select(
        'products.product_name',
        'sales_products.quantity',
        'sales_products.sales_price',
        DB::raw('(sales_products.quantity * sales_products.sales_price) as total')
    )
    ->where('sales_products.invoice_id', '=', $id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Do you have models are relationships set up for these tables?

Comment: nope. i have not made any relationships

Comment: Which output did you get instead of the expected one?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT p.product_name, sp.Quantity, sp.Total_price
FROM `products` p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(quantity) AS Quantity,
        product_id,
        SUM(sales_price*quantity) AS Total_price
    FROM `sales_products`
    GROUP BY product_id
) AS sp
    ON p.id = sp.product_id
```

This query above should help. How you should merge queries is by using `GROUP BY`. Using `GROUP BY` on the first table wrt to the product_id helps us sum up the columns accordingly.